# Content Blockers in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm trying to add a content blocker in my app, linked to my UIWebView, for blocking adds for example.
After some search i'm not sur if it's possible.
If it's possible how to link the "blockerList.json" with my WebView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but content blockers are not supported for `UIWebView`. You must use `SFSafariViewController` or launch Safari from your app.

Comment: You're welcome! You might find my [tutorial on iOS content blockers](http://www.hackingwithswift.com/safari-content-blocking-ios9) useful in your work.